# mysql query to update table depending on another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to update table 2 and set table2.mia_price = 20 where table2.mia_mi_id = 15 BUT also with the condition that the correct ram and ram_mhz exists in table1. Both tables are connected by products_id (table1.container_id, table2.mia_products_id).

For table 1, table1.addon_key.products_pc_ram = must be "4GB RAM" and table1.addon_key.products_pc_ram_mhz and "DDR4 2400 MHz"

table 1:
[image: table 1]

table 2: [image]

I have no idea to add the conditions for the table 1 because of the two columns (addon_key and addon_value). Note: table 1 has many more entries..but products_pc_ram and products_pc_ram_mhz is only once per unique container_id.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` and correlated subqueries that get the respective rows from `table2`.

```
UPDATE table1
       SET mia_price = 20
       WHERE mia_mi_id = 15
             AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM table2
                                WHERE table2.container_id = table1.mia_products_id
                                      AND table2.addon_key = 'products_pc_ram'
                                      AND table2.addon_value = '4GB RAM')
             AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM table2
                                WHERE table2.container_id = table1.mia_products_id
                                      AND table2.addon_key = 'products_pc_ram_mhz'
                                      AND table2.addon_value = 'DDR4 2400 MHz');
```

Comment: thx! works perfectly -> only table1 and table2 vice versa. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can join `table1` twice to table2 and set the conditions in the ON clause:

```
update table2 t2
inner join table1 t1
on t1.container_id = t2.mia_products_id   
and t1.addon_key = 'products_pc_ram' and t1.addon_value = '4GB RAM'
inner join table1 tt1
on tt1.container_id = t2.mia_products_id   
tt1.addon_key = 'products_pc_ram_mhz' and tt1.addon_value = 'DDR4 2400 MHz'
set t2.mia_price = 20 
where t2.mia_mi_id = 15
```

Comment: Your `OR` condition is not correct. He requires that *both* rows exist, not that either of them exists.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: maybe your code works also, but i did not tried it because of the better readability (understanding for me) of the code from sticky bit. But many thx for your reply. Maybe another one loves your code more than the other ...

Comment: You know code is not about loving. It is about efficiency, maintainability and of course readability (and others in certain cases). If all of these can be found in a piece of code then we use it.